# Way to see which elements are still loading and are hindering window.onload from firing?

Tags: javascript, html, onload, onload-event

is there a way to see which elements of a website are still loading so that window.onload can't fire yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a global way of doing this - it could well be there is none.

The only thing in that vein that comes to mind is [checking images for whether they have successfully loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript/1977898#1977898). I guess you could walk through each image and check for those properties.

However, you will be having a hard time to tell apart *failed* image load processes and those *still under way*. To make that distiction, you would have to work with the `onerror` event for each image and set some sort of "failed" flag.

What is going to be really, really hard is controlling slowly loading scripts: If a script loads slowly, there is no execution of JavaScript for that moment, so there is no way to detect any delays here except by using [the `asnyc` or `defer` properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1)... But I guess that would require fundamental changes to whatever JavaScript you are using.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think so, but if you don't want to wait till all images are loaded, you can use a [domready](http://www.google.de/#hl=de&q=domready+javascript&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=7c271a7b38b978be)-function

Comment: I'm doing that already, but thank you. :) It was just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

The network-tab in Firebug might help you.

Comment: Firebug tells me that all images are loaded when actually the mouse cursor still is displayed as a loading icon and the window.onload event hasn't triggered yet.