# new Image(), how to know if image 100% loaded or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating new image using

```
img = new Image();
img.src = image_url;
```

Then I'm assigning img.src to the img tag's src in DOM

```
$("#my_img").attr("src", img.src);
```

How can I know that img.src has 100% loaded? What is the best practice?
`img.complete` seem to me little buggy in some browsers.

So, in another words, I need to assign `img.src` to `$("#my_img")` only after `img` it was 100% loaded.

Thank you!

Comment: you can also add a check to img.complete for img.naturalWidth see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use the `load` event:

```
img = new Image();

img.onload = function(){
  // image  has been loaded
};

img.src = image_url;
```

Also have a look at:

- [Preloading and the JavaScript Image() object](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/preloading-and-the-javascript-image-object/)

Comment: Is this solution crossbrowser?

Comment: @Kirzilla: I think so, you should give it a try :)

Comment: I believe that onload is only triggered if the image is actually loaded anew. If the image is cached, then onload will not be triggered. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Can i find **MIME** type of file using above image object

Comment: Does anyone happen to know: when is the img making the http request? Is it when img.src is being changed?

Comment: @AndrewSwift: Images have `complete` property. Try `if(img.complete) console.log('already loaded')`

Comment: For anyone in the future concerned due to @AndrewSwift's comment, as long as onload is set BEFORE src is set, it's fine.

Answer (score 25):

Using the Promise pattern:

```
function getImage(url){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            var img = new Image()
            img.onload = function(){
                resolve(url)
            }
            img.onerror = function(){
                reject(url)
            }
            img.src = url
        })
    }
```

And when calling the function we can handle its response or error quite neatly.

```
getImage('imgUrl').then(function(successUrl){
    //do stufff
}).catch(function(errorUrl){
    //do stuff
})
```

Comment: This is a better solution IMO. if OP is using jQuery as tagged he can do `$.when.apply($, [])` where "`[]`" is an array of promises (i.e. support for multiple images). Worth noting the support on native promises also.

Comment: awesome answer!

Comment: Beautiful answer.

Comment: Great solution, but I suggest to use `(successUrl) => {
    //do stufff
}).catch((errorUrl) => {
    //do stuff
})` (basically use `(param) =>` instead of `function(param)` because in this way if you need to use `this` inside the promise you still have the original reference)