# setInterval issue with image not loading immediatly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a slideshow involving images which will change in accordance to the setInterval method I am using. Previously, I was having some issues with the timing of the setInterval whenever I would leave the page for a while, go to another tab or window, and then return. The slideshow timing would not flow correctly when I returned to the page - the timing of the changes were just off and as a result the jquery effects were firing at the wrong time as well.

I have now managed to at least fix that particular issue due to adding a hasFocus condition.

However, what I am finding to be the issue now, is that when I do return to the page, there is no image where the slideshow is placed. I have to wait the 6 seconds applied to the interval function.

Any idea on how I can guarantee one of the images is always displayed on the page when the user returns to the window?

```js
var bannerImages = [
      "banner1.jpeg",
      "banner2.jpg",
      "banner3.png"
    ];
    
    var currentImage = 1;
    
    $(".banner-img").fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut();
    
    setInterval(function(){
      if (currentImage > bannerImages.length-1){
        currentImage = 0;
      }

      if (document.hasFocus()) {
        $(".banner-img").fadeIn().attr("src",bannerImages[currentImage]).delay(5000).fadeOut();
        currentImage++;
      } 
    }, 6000)
```

```html
<section id="banner">
    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-responsive center-block banner-img"> 
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </section>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511200/new-image-how-to-know-if-image-100-loaded-or-not

Comment: This is a known thing in chrome where it throttles setInterval in background tabs. Only way around it I know of is to run the interval in a worker, then have an onmessage handler in regular JS do the updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not wait for the fadeIn animation to finish before changing the src attribute and fading out. I suggest a bit different logic, like this:

```
var bannerImages = [
    "banner1.jpeg",
    "banner2.jpg",
    "banner3.png"
];

var currentImage = 1;

//$(".banner-img").fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut(); //I don't think you need this.

setInterval(function(){
    if (document.hasFocus()) {
        $(".banner-img").fadeOut(100, function() {
            $(".banner-img")
                .attr("src", bannerImages[++currentImage % bannerImages.length])
                .fadeIn(100);
        });
    } 
}, 6000);
```

See this post for what that callback function is for: [How to get jQuery to wait until an effect is finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065806/how-to-get-jquery-to-wait-until-an-effect-is-finished)

Comment: thanks for the response. When I paste that code into my script, the images fail to load

Comment: Did you change the image names back to what they need to be for your example? (I just updated the answer to do that, btw)

Comment: thank you so much for this!! Awesome answer with great explanation. My mistake for not reverting the image names back to what they were, I hadnt noticed that, but now it is working fine! :)