# How do I check if an image has preloaded successfully?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if an image is loaded (no errors) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript)

After being loaded by javascript by setting img.src.

Thanks...!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `load` event like this:

```
var img = document.getElementById('imgID');

// or

var img = new Image;

img.onload = function(){
  alert('The image has been loaded');
  img.src = 'image path here';
};
```

Or when you use the `load` event of the `window`, images are loaded by then:

```
window.onload = function(){
  // everything is loaded now
};
```

Comment: this is not applicable, because i'm not setting an id to the img, as it's not being placed in a div. but thanks!

Comment: @mtay: What are you doing? Are you creating it with `new Image` for example?

Comment: @mtay: This is just an example. It works for the `Image`-object as well.

Comment: @elusive: That's right, I think I should edit my answer to reflect that too :)

Comment: @Sarfraz: You should probably add that `window.onload` does not work for dynamically created images.

Comment: @elusive: Right but OP has not really mentioned whether or not image is created dynamically. These comments should helpful for him :)

Comment: @Sarfraz: Correct. You got my upvote ;)

Comment: thanks! this ended up answering my question!

Answer (score 4):

```
var myImg = new Image();

myImg.onload = function(){
   alert('loaded');
}

myImg.src = '../images/someImage.jpg';
```

Comment: +1 for the idea, but JavaScript is case sensitive. Should be onload, not onLoad.

Answer (score 2):

Pure JavaScript (no jQuery) solution is available here for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/Sztxs/1/
(Based on existing answers)

You can integrate this into a function then use that function to preload instead of having to write new onload function for each preloaded image.

You can have whatever you want instead of alert of course.

Let us know if you need any further help. :)

Answer (score 1):

With the help this

```
var img = new Image();  
// Create image

$(img).load(function() {
    // Image Loaded notification
}).error(function () {  
    // Error Notification here
}).attr({ 
    id: "Set Id",  
    src: "Image Source",
    title: "Title Here",
    alt: "Alt here"
});
```

Comment: I think you got a syntax error here. The callback function for `.error()` lacks a closing `}`.