# How to check if naturalWidth is supported?

Tags: jquery, image, height, width

I have the following jQuery and wanted to test if naturalWidth is supported:

```
function special(image) {
    if (typeof this.naturalWidth != 'undefined') {
        //do something
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work ? Any ideas ?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript (what a mess!!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function special(image) {
    if (image && image.naturalWidth) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: :) thanks - yep seems to work when do image.naturalWidth :) thanks!

Comment: will do when it allows me :) [time limit]

Answer (score 1):

Why not just include a `naturalWidth` / `naturalHeight` polyfill? https://gist.github.com/2209957

Given that, you can write code like `alert($(img).naturalWidth())` where you'd otherwise have used `alert(img.naturalWidth)` and it should now work in all browsers, whether they support it natively or not.

Comment: +1, `naturalWidth` & `naturalHeight` are "only" IE9+ supported so I'd include a polyfill. You may want checkout this other polyfill https://gist.github.com/kroleg/5388163 , note that I have not tested it yet. And this one as well https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded