# Page Loading Without the Styling and then Eventually Loads the Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a mobile website created using ASP.NET MVC and jQuery Mobile. In the MainLayout page I load the CSS in the header from Google CDN.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css" />

</head>
```

The page first loads without the style and then after 10-20 milliseconds the page formats itself to the correct style. This all results in a small flicker which is quite noticeable. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You might be referring to this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content

Comment: I don't think 10-20 ms should be a problem for a site loading.

Comment: Not site loading but the HTML reformats itself because the CSS was loaded. This creates a flash type effect as Ian has pointed out.

Comment: Would something like this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270290/how-to-execute-code-before-window-load-and-after-dom-has-been-loaded

Comment: @john doe What I meant, couldn't think of better words.

Comment: Use a local css file