# make jquery windows.onload , not to wait for the images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preloader

so I have this issue , I have web site which has a preloader , the preloader disappears when windows.onload function is executed but I don't need this function to wait for the images because there are to many images at the first page which is needed and can't be deleted or compressed anymore.
 as well as some css and js files which will take while to be downloaded and it's a good idea to have preloader for them until they are fully loaded (it is really ugly without those files) anyway windows.onload function will wait for the images and document.ready function is only for DOM files not the css and js only the HTML.

any way to solve this issue ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13270422/4248328

Answer (score 1):

You can use some *lazy loader* plugin and then wait for `window.onload`. Basically the lazy loading plugins for images work by specifying the original image url in some custom attribute instead of in `src` attribute.
You may have a single placeholder image for all these images, so it won't take time because there are not too many images to load.