# Display images side-by-side with equal height

Tags: html, css

I would like to use CSS to display two images next to each other with a few constraints:

- Both images must be the same height. (What is the standard for the same height?)
- The combined width of both images must be equal to the total width of the container. (How to split the width of an image if it needs to be stretched?)
- The aspect ratio of both images must be maintained.

Unfortunately, the image and container dimensions are not known beforehand. Here are some example combinations of images, along with the expected output:

[image: Examples]

Comment: Is it acceptable to use Javascript or some other language to programmatically resolve this problem?

Comment: @LajosArpad Unfortunately it needs to run in an environment without JavaScript. I'm looking for CSS + HTML only. You can assume the latest CSS features though.

Comment: Is your server aware of what the pictures will be?

Comment: Your question should include some HTML and your CSS attempt. See [ask].

Comment: Question needs more thought.  can't be done. you can't force the width and the height to be something and at the same time keep the aspect ratio

Comment: @LajosArpad The images are loaded from a third party without the server having any knowledge of the size.

Comment: @DCR Only the width is fixed. A valid solution exists for every case I can think of. The height should scale such that the aspect ratio is maintained. The only thing I am not sure of is how to use CSS to solve the problem. Perhaps it is impossible using CSS alone, but hopefully not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Follow-up question: is it possible/feasible to use your server as a proxy, so that your server would load the images, do some measurements and adjust HTML/CSS accordingly before they are sent out to the browser?

Comment: It seems impossible to do this with such restrictions without using js, you need to provide a minimal runnable demo that reproduces your problem. the code you have tried (HTML + CSS + images).

Comment: What is the real scenario of your question, it seems pointless.

Answer (score 10):

This *can* be done **only if** you know in advance (or later, dynamically using JavaScript) the natural (original) width/height of your images.
Such is a trivial task if you use modern tooling for frontend development, or a backend that can serve (besides the image tag) the necessary image data in attributes or expose the values). Otherwise you might want to rely  (as already mentioned) on JavaScript.
Two examples ahead:

### Using CSS `flex`, and CSS `var()`

in where `calc()` is used to calculate the `flex-grow` value given the `--w` and `--h` CSS vars for width and height:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
}

.container img {
  flex-grow: calc(var(--w) / var(--h));
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/f08/fff" style="--w:100; --h:100;">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/200x40/0f8/fff" style="--w:200; --h:40;">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/150x200/8f0/fff" style="--w:150; --h:200;">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/250x200/f80/fff" style="--w:250; --h:200;">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/90x20/f80/fff" style="--w:90; --h:20;">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/200x60/0f8/fff" style="--w:200; --h:60;">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/80x100/08f/fff" style="--w:80; --h:100;">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/40x130/f08/fff" style="--w:40; --h:130;">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/50x50/f08/fff" style="--w:50; --h:50;">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/99x99/8f0/fff" style="--w:99; --h:99;">
</div>
```

### Using JavaScript

if for some case you're unable to know in advance the **natural** width/height of your images you could still rely on JavaScript in order to calculate the necessary `flexGrow` value, or in other words, assign dynamically the CSS vars `--w` and `--h` respective values using [setProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".container").forEach(async(elCont) => {

  const elsImages = elCont.querySelectorAll("img");

  //stackoverflow.com/a/60949881/383904
  await Promise.all([...elsImages].filter(img => !img.complete).map(img => new Promise(resolve => img.onload = img.onerror = resolve)));

  elsImages.forEach(elImg => {
    elImg.style.setProperty("--w", elImg.naturalWidth);
    elImg.style.setProperty("--h", elImg.naturalHeight);
  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
}

.container img {
  flex-grow: calc(var(--w) / var(--h));
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/f08/fff">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/200x40/0f8/fff">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/150x200/8f0/fff">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/250x200/f80/fff">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/90x20/f80/fff">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/200x60/0f8/fff">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/80x100/08f/fff">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/40x130/f08/fff">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/50x50/f08/fff">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/99x99/8f0/fff">
</div>
```

Acknowledgment and documentation:

- [CSS Flex flex-grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)
- [CSS var()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var)
- [CSS calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)
- [CSSStyleDeclaration setProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty)
- [Varying aspect-ratio images](https://www.terluinwebdesign.nl/en/css/images-of-varying-aspect-ratio-fill-available-space-but-keep-heights-equal/)
- [Callback on all images loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60949881/383904)

Comment: Your CSS is a good idea. I enjoy it! But @user2248702 has said: "the image and container dimensions are not known beforehand" and "I would like to use CSS"

Comment: thanks @MohammadMahdiKabir The container ***is*** of unknown width, but, it's indeed necessary to know (or retrieve at some point) the images aspect ratio in order to achieve the desired. I tried all the possible tricks using min-max-content, calcs, etc. to no avail.

Comment: no, can't be done given the constraints

Comment: Your demo does not meet all the restrictions, such not know the image size.

Comment: @xgqfrms exactly, that's why it's stated in **bold** that's *possible* ***only if***. I lost a bunch of hours on this interesting problem with all the available bleeding edge CSS features, and no. Without knowing the aspect-ratio it's simply not possible unless... (read the answer from the beginning). The JavaScript solution was for posterity and other users coming to this problem but being able to use JS. Mentioning backend and build systems is also for the ones with an [*XY-Problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), or forgetting that there's other possibilities.

Comment: how would this work if I were to wrap the img tag in a figure tag so that I can use the figcaption.

Comment: @AlexSuciu Use `.container figure {` in CSS, then in HTML move the styles with vars to the figures: `<figure style="--w:100; --h:100;">` and add this rule: `.container figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}` Example: https://jsfiddle.net/uzpqLke3/

Answer (score -1):

Building on the answer above, but works only if the image widths give the proportions, but in the screenshots it looks like the height is what matters.

Still trying to rotate the images to get the proportions from image height and not width, but maybe this will give someone an idea how to solve it.

I get the dimensions from the images and hide them, and then use the images as background images of the parent div.

this keep proportions of the images based on their widths, and height of the taller element.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 300px; /* Change this for testing */
}

.container > * {
  background-size: cover;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first image-wrapper" style="background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Lilium_candidum_1.jpg)">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Lilium_candidum_1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="second image-wrapper" style="background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d5/Panorama_of_the_courtyard_of_the_Great_Mosque_of_Kairouan.jpg/640px-Panorama_of_the_courtyard_of_the_Great_Mosque_of_Kairouan.jpg)">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d5/Panorama_of_the_courtyard_of_the_Great_Mosque_of_Kairouan.jpg/640px-Panorama_of_the_courtyard_of_the_Great_Mosque_of_Kairouan.jpg">
  </div>
</div>



<div class="container">
  <div class="first image-wrapper" style="background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Lilium_candidum_1.jpg)">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Lilium_candidum_1.jpg">
  </div>
   <div class="second image-wrapper" style="background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d5/Panorama_of_the_courtyard_of_the_Great_Mosque_of_Kairouan.jpg/1280px-Panorama_of_the_courtyard_of_the_Great_Mosque_of_Kairouan.jpg)">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d5/Panorama_of_the_courtyard_of_the_Great_Mosque_of_Kairouan.jpg/1280px-Panorama_of_the_courtyard_of_the_Great_Mosque_of_Kairouan.jpg">
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="first image-wrapper" style="background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Lilium_candidum_1.jpg)">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Lilium_candidum_1.jpg">
  </div>
   <div class="second image-wrapper" style="background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Panorama_of_the_courtyard_of_the_Great_Mosque_of_Kairouan.jpg)">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Panorama_of_the_courtyard_of_the_Great_Mosque_of_Kairouan.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

sorry to be a buzzkill, but

> The aspect ratio of both images must be maintained.

is like having your cake and eating it too.

if you already have those images pre-sized, it's as simple as slapping `display: flex` on the container. anything else will crop or warp the image.