# Equal height figures and not cropped

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to display a row of 2-5 figures containing an image and a caption.
The figures must have the same height and the aspect ratio of the images must be maintained.
HTML would look something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <figure style="--w:100; --h:100;">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/f08/fff" style="--w:100; --h:100;">
    <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure style="--w:200; --h:40;">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/200x40/0f8/fff" style="--w:200; --h:40;">
    <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure style="--w:150; --h:200;">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/150x200/8f0/fff" style="--w:150; --h:200;">
    <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure style="--w:250; --h:200;">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/250x200/f80/fff" style="--w:250; --h:200;">
    <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/alexgvb/pen/JjzgBpe?editors=1100)

I've found something similar here, but it doesn't work right with the figure element, unless I use object fit cover on the img tag.

[Display images side-by-side with equal height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77120785/display-images-side-by-side-with-equal-height/77145952)

Comment: Are you attempting to use custom CSS properties (`--w`,`--h`)? If so, where are those defined? They aren't in your codepen (and you should really include all your codepen code in your question itself; links can break and are thus rendered useless to future readers).

Comment: why don't you use CSS flexbox to achieve the result?

Comment: mykaf in the style attribute.

anoncephal I am using flexbox

check the codepen

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better approach to perfectly fit all the images inside the figure container.
You can use : max-height and min-height properties to limit the image dimension. Then `object-fit: cover` will maintain the image view.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
/*   border: 1px solid black;  */
}
figure img{
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
figure{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <figure >
    <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/f08/fff" style="--w:100; --h:100;">
    <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure >
    <img src="https://placehold.co/200x40/0f8/fff" style="--w:200; --h:40;">
    <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure >
    <img src="https://placehold.co/150x200/8f0/fff" style="--w:150; --h:200;">
    <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://placehold.co/250x200/f80/fff" style="--w:250; --h:200;">
    <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: the object fit cover is what I am trying to avoid to not crop the images.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that I tried

- I explicitly targeted the second figure child and set custom properties
- The second Image is now scaled downed to fit with the other images.

As the second image is a bit wider in dimensions, so its getting stretched out.

Hope this helps..

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
figure img{
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 3/2;
  object-fit: cover;
}
figure:nth-child(2) img{
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  transform: scale(1,3.3)
}
figure{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <figure >
    <img src="https://placehold.co/100x100/f08/fff">
    <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure >
    <img src="https://placehold.co/200x40/0f8/fff">
    <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure >
    <img src="https://placehold.co/150x200/8f0/fff">
    <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://placehold.co/250x200/f80/fff">
    <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```