# JavaScript deferred image load with error check

Tags: jquery, image, loading

I'm setting up a script to load images (we have a lot of them) after the page has loaded using the following:

HTML:

```
<img class="dload" data-src="/path/to/image.jpg">
```

JS:

```
$('img.dload').each(function() {
    var img = $(this);
    var src = img.data('src');
    img.attr('src',src);
});
```

As we have a lot of images there's a high probability that we may have broken images, so I'm wondering the best way to run `onerror` against a dynamically loaded `src`. I'd figure the image would need to successfully run the `.attr()` command before it could check...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript

Comment: @mgraph - the image was removed, doesn't exits - broken path.