# How to tell if the image is loading failure in a html img tag?

Tags: jquery, html, image

How to tell if the image is loading failure (404 not found, or other 4xx or 5xx erros) in a html img tag and report by a jquery callback?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('img').error(function(){
    //...
});
```

[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/error/)

An example from the docs:

```
<img alt="Book" id="book" />

$('#book')
  .error(function() {
    alert('Handler for .error() called.')
  })
  .attr("src", "missing.png");
```