# Hide DIV if no image displayed

Tags: jquery, html

I am using a slider in a page to display uploaded images. What I would like to do is hide the div if there is no image uploaded. Is there a command in PHP I could use to hide this div?

Here is my slider code

```
<div id="flex-slider" class="flexslider-main flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <img src="[types field="travel-tips-image" url="true" width="770" height="400"][/types]" alt="[wpv-post-title]" >
            <div id="credit">Photo by: [wpv-post-author]. </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

where

```
[types field="travel-tips-image" url="true" width="770" height="400"][/types]
```

is the shortcode from my wordpress plugin. So basically all I want to do is to not display that main div id="flex-slider" if there is no image.

I am thinking the best way to do this would be PHP but since I am a newbie I have no idea how to do it and a web search did not return much I could apply. Could anyone suggest some code to use? The site runs on wordpress. Thanks

---

Thanks for the reponsis. Of course my biggest problem is that I never actually wrote any JavaScript/JQuery. After your replies and comments I did some research and thought I would adapt a script I found. Here it is:

```
'$(function(){ 
// Hide div when no image 
if ($("div#flex-slider:not(img)").length) { 
$("#flex-slider").hide(); }) });'
```

This did not work though. To be honest I am not even sure where to place this or if the code is complete but this is pretty similar to what I need to do. Can anyone guide from here?

Comment: When shortcode provides no image source - does src becomes "" ?

Comment: You can do this with jQuery, just do if($('div').length == "") { $(this).hide();}

Comment: @Yuriy: When there is no image the source becomes '<div id="flex-slider" class="flexslider-main flexslider">
<ul class="slides">

</ul>
</div>'

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in JavaScript would be a lot easier:
Check this post for methods to understand if an image isnt loaded correctly: [Check if an image is loaded (no errors) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript)

And if you detect that an image isnt loaded properly, just set the css visibility property of the div to hidden;

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea how to work with JQuery/Javascript to be honest. After your post I researched it a little and tried to adapt a script as follows:

Comment: '$(function(){

  // Hide div when no image
  if ($("div#flex-slider:not(img)").length) {
    $("#flex-slider").hide();
})


});' but that is not working. Any suggestions?