# Is there any way to check reachability test of server in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, cordova-2.0.0

Is there any way to check reachability test of server .If application not able to connect server then it show a alert? is there any thing method to check..
I check the internet connection .If there is no connection then i am showing a alert .But if there is an connection but there is no reachability of server than how can i handle this.? 
 I am checking like this connection status..!!

```
setInterval(function () {
    connectionStatus = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';
    if(connectionStatus=="offline"){
        // alert("There is no connection");
    }
}, 100);



$.ajax({url: "192.168.12.171",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        statusCode: {
            200: function (response) {
                alert('status 200');
            },
            404: function (response) {
                alert('status  404 ');
            }
        }                        
 });
```

Comment: I don't think the selected answer is correct. It works only when status is 200.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To test if your server is up you will need to connect to it and check status massage:

```
$.ajax('LINK GOES HERE', {
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert('Not working');
    },
    200: function() {
      alert('Working');
    }
  }
});
```

Working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PMrDn/47/

```
$.ajax({url: "http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/json/23afca60ebf72f8d88cdcae2c4f31866/The Goonies",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        statusCode: {
            200: function (response) {
                alert('status 200');
            },
            404: function (response) {
                alert('status  404 ');
            }
        }                        
 });
```

#### EDIT :

Use this:

```
$.ajax({url: "http://192.168.12.171",
        type: "HEAD",
        timeout:1000,
        statusCode: {
            200: function (response) {
                alert('Working!');
            },
            400: function (response) {
                alert('Not working!');
            },
            0: function (response) {
                alert('Not working!');
            }              
        }
 });
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PMrDn/48/

Comment: wait checking ..tell you after 5 min..!!

Comment: when i am using your code it show code 200 ok.But when  i give my ip then i am facing problem .I am getting data from server .But alert say not connected..:(

Comment: I will write you a solution

Comment: Error 400 expects server, even if it is unreachable, status 0 will be thrown if nothing exist

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34216/discussion-between-user2563256-and-gajotres)

Comment: how do you hope the cross origin rule?

Comment: Several solutions exist, but in this case, it's the easiest one, jsonp is used instead of json.

Answer (score 0):

One hacky way that should work would be to load an image (or font, style, javascript) from the server and check whether or not that [image loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript). This method would of course only work as long as there is something to load from the server that is not restricted by CORS policies.