# Reboot a linux system and stay on client side during the time system start again

Tags: java, linux, spring-mvc, jsp

i have a Java Web Application in my Server System and i access it from client side by its ip and port (192.168.1.100:80).

> Is the possible to client (JSP) stay at reboot of system and when device restarted then it redirect to login page ?

here my below code is reboot the system by using `reboot buttom` of GUI, but after the page is going to blank and we again search the ip.

```
Process reboot = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reboot");

reboot.waitFor();
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks to reply, i know but here we may be use javascript on JSP page.

Comment: Anyways: in the above setup it is imo not relyable possible. Possible is to check if the site is up again and go to the loginpage. However a reload of the page will fail if the serving host is down.

Comment: Huh? You intend to reboot the machine your code is currently running and you assume you can just have the same code continue? I don't understand your question.

Comment: here in my gui have a `Restart buttom` fro reboot the server.

Comment: like I said after the reboot was triggered you can do ajax pings to the server and once it is up trigger an action. But again like I said a reload of the page will break it.

Comment: Hello Kai, Is it possible with ajax and how please guide me ? Thanks.

Comment: eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877639/is-there-any-way-to-check-reachability-test-of-server-in-jquery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224197/javascript-check-if-server-is-online

Comment: Thanks @kai upper link is very useful.