# Using AJAX to pass a generated image from PHP back to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a php file generating a diagram as an image - this is working fine
This php file has to communicate with javascript (via ajax) to load this image in the html

Initially I got it working by placing this in the javascript:

```
document.getElementById("img3").src="ajax.php?area=" +encodeURIComponent(area);
```

where img3 is the image in the html and ajax.php is the php file generating the image

The problem with this code however is there are a few lines after the code above executing before the image is loaded - a timing problem.

Changed javascript/ajax code to:

```
ar = new XMLHttpRequest();
if(ar.readyState == 4 || ar.readyState == 0)
{
     ar.open("GET", "ajax.php?area=" +encodeURIComponent(area), true);
     ar.send(null);
     ar.onreadystatechange = function()
     {
          if(ar.readyState == 4)
          {
               document.getElementById("img3").src = ar.response;
          }// end if
     }// end function
}// end if
```

Was with the hope I could place my lines of code inside the if(ar.readyState == 4) block which will solve the timing problem. But the image isn't loading. Any ideas?

Comment: you can try to convert your img in base64 encoding and than send it with ajax to your main page, and display it like `<img
src="data:image/gif;base64,[your resoult] />`

Comment: Is `ajax.php` outputting the image or a path to the image?

Comment: ajax.php is pushing the image with the last line: imagepng($image); I don't want to save it in a temp file for fear of concurrency conflicts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you don't really care how the image is loaded (using src or ajax) but what you want is to execute a piece of code after an image has loaded.

There are several (some better than others) ways of checking if an image is loaded. [This tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript) covers some of them.

For instance you could use the onload event to trigger a piece of code

```
document.getElementById("img").onload = function() { 
    //do the code which has to be executed after loading the image. 
}
```

They describe some problems with the event not firing when the image loads from cache, but a browser (almost) never caches a .php file with get parameters. You should check if caching is an issue for your project, based on what i understand from your project i think it is not a problem.

They suggest other options which are interesting to investigate. There is one i find interesting where they suggest using [imageloaded](http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/). That solution looks very solid.