# font in localhost sometimes "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH"

Tags: html, css, fonts

Viewing my HTML page in my browser I see an error:

> "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH"

It occurs for loading a font, and another font will be loaded.
I want to force the browser to load this font, any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript

Comment: It could be wrong content header for font and will probably disappear on other server. Better include your fonts from Google, or even better: base64 encode and place inside css (it is easy).

Comment: @skobaljic: header was ok, because it will load most of the times. I have used ttf font files on the same server as my html and css files loads. hope base64 help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

That problem seems to be the request in http. First of all check if the your http service (Apache, IIS) is ready to work with the extension of your font. In Second try to see if you are making some compress with the gzip. Disable it temporarily and see if works. When the page load what's happening on the network request? Use chrome, firefox dev tools to see.  I hope that helps.