# Proper way to check for image and video load failures in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, canvas

A common example of loading an image in JS to draw onto an HTML5 canvas is:

```
var canvas = $("#mycanvas")[0];
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'URL HERE';
img.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
```

**BUT how do we handle the case where the image failed to load?**

e.g. when loading JSON data with JQuery there's a `.fail` method for handling load failures:

```
$.getJSON(url)
    .done(function(data, statusText, jqXHR) {
        // data loaded ok
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // error loading data - ERROR HANDLING HERE
    })
;
```

Great, but is there some equivalent in JS for handling image loading errors?
Is there some other event similar to **`.onload`** but which triggers on **failure to load**? Or does `.onload` trigger in either case?

Similar problem when loading a video into a video tag:

```
var videoElement = $("#myvideo")[0];
$("#mvideo").append("<source src='URL HERE' type='TYPE STRING HERE'>");
videoElement.load();
videoElement.play();
```

i.e.  **how to we detect a load failure** so we can add error handling code?

Comment: or since this is jQuery this may be better suited: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the `onerror` property:

```
img.onerror = function() {
    this.src = "DEFAULT SOURCE FOR ERROR LOADED IMAGES";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try that shortly. Does that event apply to video elements too, or is there a different one (ref latter part of question)? Cheers