# Background images to change when all image have downloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using following script to show background image for a div element.

Problem with this is that images are large around 1MB each and they don't quickly so that background effect can be smooth. I wrapper function in `$(window).load(function () {}); but it didn't made any difference.

how can i delay background image download so that it only starts when all images are downloaded.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  var body = $('.hmcarousel');
  var backgrounds = new Array(
    "url(soml_slider_1.jpg)",
    "url(soml_slider_2.jpg)",
    "url(soml_slider_3.jpg)",
    "url(soml_slider_4.jpg)",
    "url(soml_slider_5.jpg)"
  );
  var current = 0;
  function nextBackground() {
    body.css(
      'background',
      backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]
    );
    setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
  }
  setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
  body.css('background', backgrounds[0]);
});
```

Comment: please don't forget to accept the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

I believe answer for your question is in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript).

> Another option is to trigger the onload and/or onerror events by creating an in memory image element and setting its src attribute to the original src attribute of the original image. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
$("<img/>")
    .load(function() { console.log("image loaded correctly"); })
    .error(function() { console.log("error loading image"); })
    .attr("src", $(originalImage).attr("src"))
;
```