# how to check image exist or not in my local system using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, file

We have image in D:\img\need.png. We need to know image exist or not.We tried like this:-- It's call error method always

```
$.ajax({
        url:'http://www.himansuit.com//modiyojana.jpg',
        type:'HEAD',
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert("file does not exist");
            console.log(textStatus); 
             console.log(jqXHR); 
             console.log(errorThrown); 
        },
        success: function()
        {
            alert("file exists do something here");//file exists do something here
        }
    });
```

Please guide me .What wrong in my code .How check file exist or not in my system using ajax call

We got Error this[image]

Comment: You can not access to the local filesystem from a javascript code hosted in a web page.

Comment: You will have to set up a web server and a script which then will check if a file exists and will return true or false to your script.

Comment: @Gael thanks for Reply but no need access jest checking file exist or not .First tell me it's possible or not .Please guide me

Comment: that is the same problem to check if a file exists or accessing it

Comment: I believe the only way (or the only way I know how) to do this would be to post the file url to the server and have the server check and report back.

Comment: Which server side script do you use ? If php we can check it in server end.

Comment: @krishna Please look my code once .We placed image into Server but it's always come file don't exits.but file this exist in url http://www.himansuit.com//modiyojana.jpg

Comment: @Gael Please look my code once .We placed image into Server but it's always come file don't exits.but file this exist in url himansuit.com//modiyojana.jpg

Comment: can you tell what error message is returned? If you want to check if a file exists at a given URL, you will have to have the autorisation for that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: @Gael Please look We add error

Comment: That is indeed a CORS access restriction. You can not do that with an ajax script due to security considerations.

Comment: If you want to just check if an image exists, see answers of this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

In server side use script like this.

```
<?php $filename = '/path/to/foo.txt';    if (file_exists($filename)) {echo "1";//existed
}else {    echo "0";//not}?>
```

In front end script do ,

```
$.ajax({
    url:'checkfileexists.php',
    type:'post',
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert("file does not exist");
        console.log(textStatus); 
         console.log(jqXHR); 
         console.log(errorThrown); 
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
      if(data==1)
        alert("file exists do something here");//file exists do something 
      else
       alert("not");  
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for Reply .We Placed image in server like this  http://www.himansuit.com//modiyojana.jpg now We need check image is exist or not we don't about PHP

Answer (score 0):

As told in comments, you first have to set up a web server on your local OS.  For example [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi), or even a [node web server](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server). Installation depends on your system.

Then, you have to write a script which receives a file path and check if there is a file here.

So, your ajax call will looks like that:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/script_path/script.php' //or script.js, or...
             +'?path=D:/img/need.png',
        type:'GET',
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
             console.log(textStatus); 
             console.log(jqXHR); 
             console.log(errorThrown); 
        },
        success: function( response )
        { 
           if( response )
              alert("file exists do something here");//file exists do something here
           else
              alert("file does not exist");
        }
    });
```

**edit**

To check if a file exists, hosted on a different domain, without having a CORS restriction:

```js
function checkFileExists( url ){
  
  var img= document.createElement('img');
  img.style.display= "none";
  img.onload= function(){ alert( url + " exists")};
  img.onerror= function(){ alert( url + " does not exists")};

  img.src= url;
}

checkFileExists("http://www.himansuit.com/modiyojana.jpg");
checkFileExists("http://www.fakedomain.com/modiyojana.jpg");
```