# How can I let a function start, only when an other function has fully started?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem. I have a fullscreen (not background! only for my intro on my onepage website.) image slide. (Created with backstretch, the real jQuery code is in an other .js file.) You'll see it in the code below. Now I have a problem. I've put text in the center over it which has the same cycle duration, so that it is changing the image at the same time as the text does. But when I upload the webpage to a server, the image is loading slower than the text. The result is, that the Text cycle starts before the image slider. Can I make a function, so that the text only starts cycling, when the image cycle has begun? I have already tried the "unload" function, but then the image is faster than the text. (It would also be okay to include a loading wheel when I open the website, so that the whole site can load.. Tell me if you don't understand what I mean)

```html
    <!-- Intro Header -->
<header class="intro">
    <!-- Backstretch JS -->
  <!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.backstretch.js"></script> <script>
$.backstretch([
"images/myimage1.png",
"images/myimage2.png",
"images/myimage3.png",
"images/myimage4.png"
], {
fade: 750,       //Speed of Fade
duration: 5000     //Time of image display
});
</script>
  
<div class="brand-heading">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    var messages = [],
        index = 0;

    messages.push('Message 1');
    messages.push('Message 2');
    messages.push('Message 3');

    function cycle() {
        $('#some-id').html(messages[index]);
        index++;

        if (index === messages.length) {
            index = 0;
        }

        setTimeout(cycle, 5750);
    }

    cycle();
});
</script>
<div id="some-id"></div>
</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the backstretch docs, I would use [backstretch.before](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch#backstretchbefore) and/or [backstretch.after](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch#backstretchafter) methods.

```
$(function () {
    var messages = [],
    messages.push('Message 1');
    messages.push('Message 2');
    messages.push('Message 3');

    $(window).on("backstretch.after", function (e, instance, index) {
        $('#some-id').html(messages[index]);
    });
});
```

Comment: What does alert( messages[index] ) display?

Comment: Where do I have to put the alert? Because if i am doing it, there is no alert popping up..

Answer (score 0):

Use the properties complete and naturalWidth for checking the image is loaded.

It's quite simple. Check if complete and naturalWidth is > 0: image ok.

```
function IsImageOk(img) {

   if (!img.complete) {
      return false;
   }

   if (typeof img.naturalWidth !== "undefined" && img.naturalWidth === 0) {
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

Read more here: [Check if an image is loaded (no errors) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

As MazzCris has said (But I'll just provide clarification if you need it), use [backstretch.after](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch#backstretchafter) instead of your `setTimeout(cycle, 5750);`

The code would be:

```
var messages = [],
    index = 0;

messages.push('Message 1');
messages.push('Message 2');
messages.push('Message 3');

function cycle() {
    $('#some-id').html(messages[index]);
    index++;

    if (index === messages.length) {
       index = 0;
    }
}

$(window).on("backstretch.after", function (e, instance, index) {
    cycle();
});
```

If you want to keep `cycle()` as a callable function that is.

Side note: You can define the `messages` array with the values in it, without having to use `messages.push`, unless you want to do that for some reason.

If that was just the way you happened to do it, you can change it to:

```
var messages = ['Message 1', 'Message 2', 'Message 3'],
    index = 0;
```

Comment: @heyho are you sure it's because of the action? And what do you mean it dissapears? Does it come up and go away again?