# Why isn't jQuery error detecting the missing images in this page?

Tags: jquery

Code:

```
<img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/881575a2c5c2c37d6de9166e384ad596?d=gravatar_default&amp;s=50&amp;r=G" class="avatar user-40-avatar avatar-50 photo" width="50" height="50" alt="Profile picture of eagink@gmail.com">

$('.avatar-50').error(function() {
  $(this).hide()
})
```

(No image is being hidden).

As you can see some of the images are not loading:

[image]

Why is this? And how to detect those unloaded pictures?

Live site: http://www.chineselearnonline.com/members/

Comment: I would set up the error handler before loading

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: You need to assign the error handler outside the onload event since that is AFTER all images have loaded

Comment: @mplungjan Hey, it worked.

Comment: I know :)..............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the error handler outside the onload event, BEFORE the image tags since now you assign the error handler AFTER all images have loaded

Alternative

```
<img onerror="this.style.display='none'" ...>
```

or

```
<img onerror="this.src='blank.gif'" ...>
```

or after the fact (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1977898/295783)):

```
$(function() {
  $(".avatar-50").each(function() {
    if (!this.complete || (typeof this.naturalWidth !== "undefined" && this.naturalWidth === 0)) {
      $(this).hide();
   }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should place the script inside document.ready:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.avatar-50').error(function() {
          $(this).hide()
       })
    });
```

Comment: It is and that is the problem. Read my comments and answer

Comment: No, that is his problem