# Detect bad / forbidden image links

Tags: javascript, image, media

Is there a way to quickly fetch an image from provided link with js and see if it is valid? i.e see if it links to plain image like this [example](http://i.huffpost.com/gen/769154/images/o-BEAVER-facebook.jpg) or catch cases when some websites redirect you to other pages i.e. not to image.

Comment: check if it ends with .jpg or .png??

Comment: Check the mimetype of the response? And what do you mean by "forbidden"?

Comment: you can load the image inside a <img offscreen. then query it for it's dimensions. if the image is valid and has loaded it should have width/height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple checking if it is a image link you can use this.

```
function checkURL(url) {
    return(url.match(/\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$/) != null);
}
```

When you want a bullet proof way of checking if the image is a legit image you can use this.

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/qKtra/

JS:

```
function testImage(url, callback, timeout) {
    timeout = timeout || 5000;
    var timedOut = false, timer;
    var img = new Image();
    img.onerror = img.onabort = function() {
        if (!timedOut) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            callback(url, "error");
        }
    };
    img.onload = function() {
        if (!timedOut) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            callback(url, "success");
        }
    };
    img.src = url;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        timedOut = true;
        callback(url, "timeout");
    }, timeout); 
}


function record(url, result) {
    document.body.innerHTML += "<span class='" + result + "'>" + 
        result + ": " + url + "</span><br>";
}   

testImage("http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344291068_HdnTo-Ti.jpg", record);

testImage("http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/invalid344291068_HdnTo-Ti.jpg", record);

testImage("http://www.cnn.com/foo.jpg", record);

testImage("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png", record);
```

CSS:

```
.success {
    color: green;
}
.error, .timeout {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here's a trick using jquery:

```
$("<img/>")
    .on('load', function() { console.log("image loaded correctly"); })
    .on('error', function() { console.log("error loading image"); })
    .attr("src", "image_url_here");
```

found the solution here:
[Check if an image is loaded (no errors) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript)