# TestCafe: Check for Images

Tags: javascript, html, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I am looking for a way to check if all img src from a specific page results in a 200. I got this script so far:

```
test('Check if all images exist', async t => {
    var images = Selector('img');
    var count    = await images.count;
    for(var i=0; i < count; i++) {
        var url = await images.nth(i).getAttribute('src');
        if(!url.startsWith('data')) {
            console.log(url);
            console.log(getHTTPStatus(url));
            console.log(await t.navigateTo(url));
        }
    }
});
```

Now we are able to read the src attribute and skip them if they start with "data" to avoid base64 images. If I use the `navigateTo` command now I see the image in the browser, but am not able to do anything else. Are you able to help me checking things?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript

Comment: TestCafe is a NodeJS Checking tool, I have no jQuery available so I am not able to use it =(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check that all image responses have 200 status, you can use TestCafe `ClientFunction`:

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `fixture`
    .page `https://www.google.com`;

test('Check if all images exist', async t => {
    var images        = Selector('img');
    var count         = await images.count;
    var requestsCount = 0;
    var statuses      = [];

    var getRequestResult = ClientFunction(url => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.open('GET', url);

            xhr.onload = function () {
                resolve(xhr.status);
            };

            xhr.send(null);
        });
    });


    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var url = await images.nth(i).getAttribute('src');

        if (!url.startsWith('data')) {
            requestsCount++;

            statuses.push(await getRequestResult(url));
        }
    }

    await t.expect(requestsCount).eql(statuses.length);

    for (const status of statuses)
        await t.expect(status).eql(200);
});
```

Or, you can use some addition module, for example, a `request` to simplify the code:

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';
import request from 'request';

fixture `fixture`
    .page `https://www.google.com`;

const getLocation = ClientFunction(() => window.location.href);

test('Check if all images exist', async t => {
    var images          = Selector('img');
    var count           = await images.count;
    var location        = await getLocation();
    var requestPromises = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var url = await images.nth(i).getAttribute('src');

        if (!url.startsWith('data')) {
            requestPromises.push(new Promise(resolve => {
                return request(location + url, function (error, response) {
                    resolve(response ? response.statusCode : 0);
                });
            }));
        }
    }

    var statuses = await Promise.all(requestPromises);

    for (const status of statuses)
        await t.expect(status).eql(200);
});
```

Comment: Whow, thank you very much! I just tested this and it worked in all my tests without a problem! I did not know that it would be that easy to do this, tried out a lot of stuff this morning.