# In Javascript how to execute the image.onload function first before moving ahead with rest of the process

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, callback

Below is my code that I execute:

```
    <head>
        <script>
            function uploadFile() {
                console.log('here');
                var x = document.getElementById('img');
                console.log(x.files);

                var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                var file = x.files.item(0);
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
                img.onload = function () {
                    alert("alert1 : this alert should come before");
                    alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
                }
                alert("alert2: this alert should come later");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='file' id='img' accept="image/*"/>
        <input type='submit' value='Upload' onclick='uploadFile()'/>    
    </body>
<html>
```

I want **alert1** to be displayed before **alert2**.

Currently, first alert2 is displayed before alert1.

Comment: You don’t execute the onload function. It executes when the image loads. You don’t know when that will be, which is why you pass in a callback function. If you want alert2 to fire after this it needs to be in that callback.

Comment: you would probably need to look at Promises if you need to trigger things in particlar sequence

Answer (score 1):

How [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XUL/Attribute/image.onload) for `image.onload` says:

> This event handler will be called on the image element when the image
>   has finished loading

It seems that the image wasn't loaded before the second alert was executed. You can [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1977898/9926721) that the image is loaded and after that handle it in your way.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way to show alert2 second. Because alert1 is depended on image load.

```
img.onload = function () {
    alert("alert1 : this alert should come before");
    alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
    alert("alert2: this alert should come later");
}
```