# Animate native lazy load image (loading='“lazy”)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, images with the attribute `loading="lazy"` (https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading/) are displayed immediately when loaded, i.e. without fade-in effect.

Is there a way to animate images with the `loading="lazy"` attribute when they are loaded and preferably without JavaScript?

I know, there are many lazyloading JavaScript libraries, but just because loading is now done natively by the browser, the handling via JavaScript feels like a step back again.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to use a simple jQuery solution, since its already used in my case:

```
 //fade in lazy loaded images
 $('article img').on('load', function(){
    $(this).addClass('loaded');
 });
```

The images have 0 opacity by default and opacity 1 from the new class

```
img{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}

img.loaded{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This is not graceful as users w/o JS wont see the images ... but frankly i don't care ^^ To be honest, who has JS disabled?

Comment: Thanks, this could be a progressive way. For disabled JS Users, you could initially add a no-js class and change the class to js if js is enabled. Like modernizr does. (https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/src/setClasses.js#L23)

Comment: Something like :loaded pseudo would be nice in css in the future.

Comment: This is a really neat solution but on testing it, I see it doesn't work on images which are initially visible. When scrolling, the images do indeed fade in nicely but the images in the header remain at opacity: 0.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not as simple as the simple jQuery solution above.
`.on('load')` does not work properly for all Browsers (like Chrome) as discussed here: [Check if an image is loaded (no errors) with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-with-jquery)