# JQuery error() function not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have the following image element that it's src does not exists.  I want to use the jquery error function to detect if it has not loaded and replace the src with a generic image that I know exists.  This works in chrome and firefox but on in IE.  Why does this not work in IE and are there any workarounds?  Thanks!

```
<img id="main" src="missing-image.jpg" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#main").error(function () {
            $("#main").attr("src", "generic.jpg");
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: take a look an similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263359/how-can-i-determine-if-an-image-has-loaded-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: It looks like jquery ignores .error() in IE if there is no file extension on the source. I had to use the workaround Carlos mentions in the comment above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timing issue?

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/pFEJu/)

```
<img id="mainImage" src="placeholder.jpg" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mainImage").error(function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "generic.jpg");
  });
  $("#mainImage").attr("src","possibly_missing_image.jpg");
});

</script>
```

Comment: This still doesn't work in IE.  I dont believe that "main" is a reserved word.

Comment: Note - This DOES NOT work in IE if your image source has no file extension. It looks like jquery ignores .error() in IE if there is no file extension on the source. I used something like this as a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263359/how-can-i-determine-if-an-image-has-loaded-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: Something like this what? The deferred example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9333069/295783) ?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem with ie and setting the img src to itself allowed enough time for ie to catch the image error

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mainImage").error(function () { 
    $(this).attr("src", "generic.jpg");
  })
  .each(function() {
  $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("src"));
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function () {
        $("#main").bind('error abort', function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "generic.jpg");
        });
    });
```

Comment: This will bind to onabort event of image which will be fired in case of no image source.

Comment: I think you're confusing `.error` with the `error()` function available as an argument of `.ajax()`

Comment: @adam - Image tag has onabort event as well.

Comment: I tried changing to bind and adding "abort" but that doesn't either in IE.  Is IE missing the onError event that would be mapped to?