# Jquery - When to use "this" and when to use "$(this)"?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery $(this) vs this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this)

What is the difference between "this" and "$(this)"?

How do I know which one to use?

Related, I think:

With each, you have the optional parameters.
How is the "i" different than "this" (or "$(this)")?

```
$('img').each(function(i) { ....code }
```

vs.

```
$('img').each(function() { ....code }
```

Comment: The question is similar but a bit different, and it is pretty hard in general to find information about "this", since search engines generally ignore it.

Comment: The question may be a duplicate, but Joseph's answer is better than the one chosen on the other question. I was only able to solve my problem after reading these answers here, so I hope they are preserved for future searchers.

Comment: Also, part of the reason this may be a duplicate is because it is pretty hard to search for "this" on Google. In fact, when I first came across OOP, it took me A LONG TIME to find information on "this" as well as "::" (paamayim nekudotayim).

Comment: What is this question similar to? Link?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the `this` object doesn't change.  It is the owner of the function.  It is, in most cases like this, simply a node and you can reference all of its properties like `this.className`. (think of it as you would a node or whatnot that you get with `document.getElementById`).  It is just the "owner" of the function.

Therefore, you are just passing the `this` object to jQuery's `$()`.

Conclusion:  If you want to use jQuery functions for the current node, use `$(this)`.  But if you want to access the objects own properties (e.g. `.name`, `className`, `.id`), use simply `this`.

Comment: I think that quote about `this` is a bit misleading.

Comment: @alex please explain or maybe even reword my answer.

Comment: I'd just remove the quote, your answer is great.

Comment: So, if I'm inside ".each", I am iterating through a collection. Should I use "$(this).width()", "this.width", or "i.width()"?

Comment: @alex oh ok. I'll do that.  Thank you for letting me know.  :)

Comment: @ButtleButkus it would most likely be `$(this).width()` if you are using `.each()` on a node list (e.g. `$(".thing").each(...`) because `.width()` is a jQuery method.

Comment: So, once inside of jquery's ".each", "this" and "$(this)" refer to the same thing - the current element in this iteration over the collection. And choose either one, depending on whether you want to use jquery methods/properties or plain javascript ones. Correct?

Comment: That is correct, but `this` is always the same `this`.  You're just passing it to jQuery if you place it in `$()`;

Comment: Thanks Joseph, yours was the clearest and most to-the-point answer.

Comment: @ButtleButkus Thanks :) Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 5):

this is for javascript, $(this) for jQuery.
you can use $(this) for every functions of jQuery, not the case for this.

Edit:
For your example the i is just the incremented number that he is on (0 the 1st 10 the 11the) the $(this) is the element img precisely you can do either :

```
$(this).on('click', function() { console.log(123); });
or
$('img').eq(i).on('click', function() { console.log(123); });
```

Edit2:
Here is a usage of this:

```
var sorter = {
    sort: function() {
        console.log('sorting');
    },
    requestSorting: function() {
        this.sort();
    }
}
sorter.requestSorting.bind(sorter);
```

In this example it's exactly used like the $this in PHP class.
That's why I said it's more for pure javascript functions.

Comment: *this is for javascript* What does that exactly mean?

Comment: He means to say that the keyword, "this", is a basic javascript functionality, whereas "$(this)" is jQuery specific, not basic javascript.

Comment: user1040899, thanks for the edit. It helps clarify what "i" would do, but doesn't explain why/when it would be preferred over using "$(this)", which seems simpler to use. +1

Comment: I edited a 2nd time. Please correct me alex if you think I'm saying something wrong...

Comment: I think Joseph answer is better then mine !

Comment: Yes it is. It is more focused well worded. It really is a good answer. It clarifies in a few sentences what others spend dozens of sentences skirting around. But your explanation of "i" is good. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`this` in jQuery generally points to a DOM element, such as `HTMLSelectElement`.

Rewrapping it with the jQuery function allows you to call jQuery methods on it.

Comment: What do you think of what user1040899 said, that "this" is for javascript, vs. $(this) for jquery? As I understand it, the "$" is actually shorthand for the entire JQuery object.

Comment: @ButtleButkus see my answer for information on that.

Answer (score 1):

Putting this inside $() turns this into a jquery object, with the ability to have all the typical jQuery methods called on it.  this by itself it just a normal javascript reference to a given object/element.

Comment: So I can always put $() around "this" to use jquery methods on it and access jquery properties?

Comment: yes, that is the standard convention for creating jquery objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".class" ).click( function () {

  $( this ).load( "/path/to/file.html" );

} );
```

In this example, `this` is referring to the `.class` div and would load the contents of `file.html` into said div when you clicked on it.

So click on `.class`, `file.html` gets loaded into it.

Comment: Very interesting trick. +1. But doesn't really clarify the difference between the $(this) and this or explain when to use which.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you need $(this) or not depends on the context you're working in.

Need it:

- When handling jQuery Events
  this is passed as the DOM element that triggered the event $(this) turns DOM element into a jQuery object
- Anytime you get a DOM element
  Other instances where you have a DOM element (or an object) and want to turn it into a jQuery object

Don't need it:

- Inside of a jQuery Plug-in
  jQuery plug-in (jquery.fn)  function this is a jQuery object already so no need to apply $(this) in here.

No harm done in $(this) even if this is a jQuery object because jQuery will just return the same object.

Comment: Ok, but what about inside the ".each" loop? In another question I had some code where I use "this" instead of "$(this)" and an answerer said it was wrong. Inside the ".each" loop am I not accessing a jquery object or is it a DOM element? (here is the other question I am referring to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463878/trying-to-set-css-property-left-to-using-jquery-centering-image-inside-div/8463929#8463929)