# Native JavaScript to detect when images are loaded

Tags: javascript, html, image, preloader

I'm writing a JS 'slideshow' (it's not a normal slideshow: the images change quickly so they have to be preloaded), and I'd like to have a `loader` on while the images are `preloading`.
To do this, I suppose I need to detect when each image is loaded (there's 36).
Right now I'm adding the images by appending the tags to the slideshow's main `div` (and removing the default static image, which users without JS see), but please tell me if you think there's a better way of doing it.
Then they are shown to the user one at the time.
Is there a cross-browser 'native' way of detecting when the images have loaded?
Thank you, StackOverflow!

---

I think I found an acceptable solution [on this site](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/preloadimagesplus.shtml).
Still, I'd be happy if you could point out to me any bugs or ways to make the script better!
I did see he leaves out all the `;`...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine if an image has loaded, using Javascript/jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263359/how-can-i-determine-if-an-image-has-loaded-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: I think I found an acceptable solution (I still haven't tested it though) on this site: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/preloadimagesplus.shtml.
Thanks anyway for answering!

Answer (score 1):

Use the image onload Event:

```
<img src="..." onload="foo()" />
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. The problem with this is that I need some way of 'pausing' the loop generating the `<img>` tags until this image has loaded, in order to be sure that _all_ the images have loaded completely before starting the 'slideshow'

Answer (score 1):

Try smthing like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
        var images = new Array()
        function preload() {
            for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
                images[i] = new Image()
                images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
            }
        }
        preload(
            "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-001.jpg",
            "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-002.jpg",
            "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-003.jpg"
        )
    //--><!]]>
</script>
```