# How can I delay JavaScript code until all the images are loaded into memory

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have no JavaScript knowledge. I'm trying to delay the  `$('#image').reel` code until the image is loaded so I can get the image width value.

```
   stitched: imgwidth,
   loops: false,
   frames: 30,
   frame: 1,
   wheelable: false
   // speed: 0,
   // timeout: 1
}); 

function imageReel() {
    $('#image').empty();
    var image = '<img id="image" src=\'images/' + arrReel[imgcount] + '.png\' width="1000" height= "700" />';
    $('#image-wrapper').html(image);
    $('#image').reel({
        stitched: imgwidth,
        loops: false,
        frames: 30,
        frame: 1,
        wheelable: false
        // speed: 0,
        // timeout: 1
    });
    console.log(imgwidth);
}
```

**Attempt 1 based on first answer**

```
 $('#image').empty();
        // var image = '<img id="image" src=\'images/'+arrReel[imgcount]+'.png\' width="1000" height= "700" />';

      $(function(){
      image=new Image();
      image = '<img id="image" src=\'images/'+arrReel[imgcount]+'.png\' width="1000" height= "700" />';

        image.onload=function(){
           $('#image-wrapper').html(image);
           $('#image').reel({

            stitched:    imgwidth,
            loops:       false,
            frames:       30,
            frame:        1,
            wheelable: false, 
            // speed:       0,
            // timeout:     1
          }); 
    };
    $('body').append(image);
});
```

**Result. Still gives me 0 width plus creates multiple images**

**Attempt 2 based on kilian's answer**

```
 <div id="image-wrapper"><img id="image" src='images/outsidedark.png' width="1000" height= "700" onload="someFunction()" /></div>

        function someFunction()
        {
            console.log(imgwidth);
            $('#image').reel({

            // stitched:    3208,

            stitched:    imgwidth,
            loops:       false,
            frames:       30,
            frame:        1,
            wheelable: false, 
            // speed:       0,
            // timeout:     1
          });


        }
```

**Result** The image keeps getting loaded. Possible because of the plugin but I think I need  onload to only load that function once and its loading it multiple times. The width is still 0 and because of the console log that 0 keeps getting displayed like its stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine if an image has loaded, using Javascript/jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263359/how-can-i-determine-if-an-image-has-loaded-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: No, it's different. You need the image onload event for this one, not the document onload event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what is `reel` jquery plugin(is it plugin?)... But following code shows real image width and height.

```
$(function(){
    var image=new Image();
    image.src='http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png';

    image.onload=function(){
        console.log($(this).height());
        console.log($(this).width());
    };
    $('body').append(image);
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it is a jquery plugin.

Answer (score 1):

using `image.onload = function () { //your code here }` should work, but I have noticed that in some browsers (i.e `Chrome`) if the browser caches the image, the `onload` event no longer fires.

**UPDATE:**

After bit of research i've discovered [this jQuery plugin](https://raw.github.com/peol/jquery.imgloaded/master/ahpi.imgload.js) which solves the problem with the browsers caching images. Also, it apears to be cross-browser. Give it a try.

Comment: Ok I actually need it to work on the ipad. I have tried it but only in chrome so will give it a try on the ipad.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event.

```
$(window).load(function(){
  // your code here
});
```

Comment: the image is not part of the dom on `load`. he inserts the image dynamically.

Comment: Also: `load()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8; it's in the page you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Attach an onload event to your image element.

```
<img onload="someFunction()" ... >


function someFunction() {
    // image.reel part
}
```