# Is there a way to provide a fallback (local) image when the preferred (external/server/remote/cloud) image fails to load?

Tags: jquery, html

I have anchor tags like so:

```
<a href=\"http://www.duckbill.com" target=\"_blank\"><img height=\"160\" width=\"160\" src=\"http://images.duckbill.com/PlatypiOnVacation.jpg\" alt=\"Platypi playing Pinochle and eating Pizza in Panama\" /></a>
```

...that sometimes fail to load the src image; in such cases I'd like to, after a sufficient delay (a couple of seconds), replace that with:

```
<a href=\"http://www.duckbill.com" target=\"_blank\"><img height=\"160\" width=\"160\" src=\"Content/Images/PlatypiOnVacation.jpg\" alt=\"Platypi playing Pinochle and eating Pizza in Panama\" /></a>
```

I know that I  could probably do that in jQuery, but how would I be able to programmatically determine that the remote file did not load and, when such is the case, respond by using the fallback image?

### UPDATE

I like Brad Christie's answer for truly unavailable images, but I want to never show an "unavailable" - just use a local one if a remote one is not available at the moment. I like this: http://www.cirkuit.net/projects/jquery/onImagesLoad/example1.html but how to determine programmatically that the image failed?

Comment: If it were a local image (which is what's being used in your question) you could use your webserver to do it.

Comment: [search `[javascript] check if image is loaded`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+check+if+image+is+loaded) --> http://stackoverflow.com/q/1977871, http://stackoverflow.com/q/263359, etc

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<img src="http://remotecdn.com/myimage.jpg"
     data-failover="/assets/notfound.jpg" />
```

Then:

```
<script>
  $('img[data-failover]').error(function(){
    var failover = $(this).data('failover');
    if (this.src != failover){
      this.src = failover;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Attempt to load the actual source, but in the event of an error use the `failover` data property to convert it to a local resource. Since we're keeping the supplemental information separated, it should gracefully fail in browsers that can't/won't support it.

More information about [`.error()`](http://api.jquery.com/error/).

Comment: What happens if the local image file does not load either? Right, you run into an infinite loop. And some day some nasty person or software has removed the file. So you should clear the `onerror` handler, e.g. with `this.onerror = function () {}"`, before assigning to `this.src`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I have found is that image requests sometimes hang for quite a while. If you want to show something to the user when that happens you can set a CSS background on the img element with a 'not available' icon etc. Then if the image does eventually load it will still display.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".thumb").each(function(){
        if(!this.complete){
            $(this).css({background:'url("not-available.gif")'});
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: The problem with that is that when the remote image finally loads, if it has some transparent areas, the fallback image will be seen through it.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a CSS solution: overlap images.

In my case I had 2 profile images, one image is of the user, if it exists, if it does not exist, then an avatar will be used. We don't know if the user image exists.

So if the intended image does not exist, the avatar shows up :)

//CSS

```
.avatar {
    position:relative;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

.avatar img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
```

//HTML

```
<div class="avatar">
    <img height="40" width="40" src="/assets/users/avatar.jpg">
    <img height="40" width="40" src="/assets/users/joe.jpg" >
</div>
```

Comment: The only issue with this one is that you're always going to be loading both images even if you don't need to. Not a terrible thing, but a cost to look at.